# How do I write a loop which sums up my precipitation values

Tags: r, loops

I am looking for a loop which goes over a vector of precipitation values and adds the value to the previous value
for example:

```
precipitation <- c(0, 2, 0, 0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 0, 1)
```

and I would love to get a vector which adds up the values like this

```
precipitationSum <- c(0, 2, 0, 0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 0, 1)
print(precipitationSum)
```

Hope the description makes sense!

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Avoid loops if possible in R. There are many functions that you can apply to vectors directly such as `sum()`,  or `mean()`. You can also perform operations such as multiplication or addition to an entire vector without looping through the individual elements `precipitation + 1` will return a vector with every element increased by 1.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `cumsum` function to calculate the cumulative sum of a vector:

```
precipitationSum <- cumsum(precipitation)
```

This gives you the following result:

```
[1] 0.0 2.0 2.0 2.1 2.6 3.2 3.2 4.2
```

Comment: Thank you ! Didn't know about that function ! It worked :)

Answer (score 0):

```r
precipitation <- c(0, 2, 0, 0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 0, 1)
precipitation = unlist(precipitation)
print("This loop calculates the partial sums of precipitation")
myList <- unlist(list(1:length(precipitation)))
print(myList)
for(i in 1:length(precipitation)) {
  if(i == 1) {
      myList[i] <- precipitation[i]
  }
  else {
      myList[i] <- myList[i-1] + precipitation[i]
  }
}

print(myList)
```